# Tool for web server redirect management?

Tags: webserver

I'm considering rolling my own, but just in case there's a good piece of software already available, I'm asking here: Is there something that will provide an interface to webserver redirect configuration, and allow redirects to be managed by a fairly non-technical userbase. The following requirements must be fulfilled:

- Open-source
- Apache
- Support for internal / external redirects
- Support for both web-server config and htaccess or meta-refresh files (for users who cannot restart the server)
- Date range for validity

Comment: Depending on your goal, you may be going about this the wrong way. I don't know any such system that exists with your requirements. There are a few nonfree software packages out there but you are probably best off rolling your own solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use either a [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) script/program, or a static map (whichever is easiest for you/your users).

Check http://rewrite.drbacchus.com/rewritewiki/RewriteMap out for a basic example of the scripting capabilities. The performance hit is not as huge as you'd think because the process is launched one time only and stays alive until Apache is brought down. So be careful with resource management.

Comment: I'm familiar with RewriteMap, and that actually formed part of the homespun solution I ended up with. The question was more about storage of redirects - e.g. via flat text files or a database - and any associated functionality: handling different HTTP status codes, time-management, etc. This must be a pretty common requirement (unless it happens to be baked into your CMS).
Since this question has had next-to-no traffic, I'll mark your answer as correct, though - it's still useful info. and a good starting point.