# How to safely allow web-server to write to its own docroot?

Tags: security, apache, webserver

As a follow up to [an earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186900/tool-for-web-server-redirect-management) that attracted a whole zero answers, I'm wondering about the possibilities of allowing a web server (apache) to write to its own document root (Linux), in order to dynamically create meta-redirect files.

Of course, this sounds incredibly dangerous, and I'm wary of going the whole hog and granting the web-server user full write-access to its own docroot. Is there a more appropriate way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's usually done is to allow writes only to subdirectories, hopefully located in a noexec mounted partition.

That said, it seems to me that you should just create a set of [RewriteMap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) directives to do your dynamic redirection, there's no need to write files in the document root to accomplish that.

I answered similarly in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/186900/tool-for-web-server-redirect-management#197688), just for completeness.

Answer (score 3):

Use mod-rewrite, mapping to a program that you write to do the rewrites based on database records or some other mechanism.

Instructions here:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_rewrite.html

Look for: "External Rewriting Program" on the page

Edit (from Vinko in the comments, 2.2 docs)

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap

Answer (score 1):

This is incredibly dangerous if you are trying to achieve what your previous question was getting at.

If you are going to go this route, you'll want a ton of testing to prevent people from forcing webserver instructions into htaccess files.